# How to stop Wicket creating multiple instances of Guice-injected singletons?

Tags: java, singleton, wicket, guice

I'm a new Guice user, having been a long-time user of Spring IoC. I have a number of `@Singleton` classes for my service tier, which I understand is roughly equivalent to Spring's default bean scope.

However, when I am using `@Inject` in my Wicket pages a CGLib proxy of the target objects is created each time the page is constructed, thus creating new instances of my supposed-singletons.

Note that I'm injecting concrete classes, not interfaces.

How can I use `@Inject` and retrieve the single singleton instance of my Guice-injected objects?

**Updated: Solution as per Sven's accepted answer**

Inject interfaces in Wicket components rather than concrete classes. Despite much discussion on the subject in the linked thread, this appear to be the only practical solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following issue gives some background:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-1130

Comment: Thanks Sven. I had got as far as creating a no-arg constructor to keep cglib happy but for some reason hadn't quite made the association between that and the multiple singleton creation.